# Clean install of 12.10 - reused 12.04 /home. Cannot start unity/login for legacy/imported user

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, upgrade, lightdm

I have separate disks for / and /home.  I did have 12.04 installed but decided to do a clean install (format and install) of 12.10. I created my user at install.  I should be able to login, right? Well, I can't.  LightDM comes up with my username and I enter my password, but it just goes back to the login screen.  Is there something I should delete from my old profile or ~?

I can login to the terminal. My files and directories are there in /home.